# an array which takes multiple elements of different data type

Tags: c, arrays, typedef

I want to take information of a class which contains student name,roll no. and print it
I used structure but code not working

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int size,i,j;

struct Student
{
    char name[50];
    int number;
};

typedef struct Student info1;
info1 print[100];

int main()
{
     printf("Size of class : ");
     scanf("%d",&size);


    for(j=0;j<(20);)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=size;i++)
        {

            printf("%d.Name:",i);
            scanf("%s",&info1.name);// i get an error here that an exp is expected
            print[j]=info1.name; // i get an error here that an exp is expected
            j++;
            printf("Rollno:");
            scanf("%d", &info1.number);// i get an error here that an exp is expected
            print[j]=info1.number;// i get an error here that an exp is expected

        }

    }   
    for (j = 0;j <(20);)
    {
        printf("%s Name", print[j]);
        j++;
        printf("%d Rollno", print[j]);
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

while debugging I get the following errors:

> expected exp before info1

Answer (score 1):

In your code, for all the usage like

```
 scanf("%s",&info1.name);
             ^^^^^
```

are wrong, as `info` is an alias to a datatype, not a variable.

You have already defined a variable of that type, `print`, make use of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Student
{
    char name[50];
    int number;
};
```

This is fine and unexceptional

```
 typedef struct Student info1;
 info1 print[100];
```

This strongly suggests to me you don't know what you are doing. info1 is now an alias for struct Student. Rather an odd name. Then you are creating a buffer called print with a capacity of a hundred.

We can easily fix your compile time errors. You can assign a strudnet

```
 struct Student astudent;   

 print[i] = astudent;
```

and you have to initialise him first

```
  scanf("%s %d", astudent.name, &astudent.number);
```

but you can't assign to the type "info1". And "print" is a very poor choice for an array of students. Make it "printlist" at least.